# Cannot resolve method setImageScaleType MediaView class?

Tags: java, android, admob, mediaview

When i try to set the scaleType of the **mediaView** it says `"Cannot resolve method"`.

[image]

Now the weird thing is it's a property i found in the MediaView Class so i don't really understand why it says `"cannot resolve method setImageScaleType"`.

> Android admob docs

[image]

**EDIT**

Im currently using this version of play-services-ads which is an outdated version.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.1'
```

I'm using this version because my project is using libraries which are not compatible with Android X artifacts.

> Latest version of play-services-ads is 18.2.0 which also migrated to
>   Android X.

Any workaround so i can still use latest version without fully migrating to Android X ?

Comment: What is your import for `MediaView`?

Comment: @ianhanniballake import com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.MediaView;

Comment: @ianhanniballake Any idea what can be the reason for this ?

Comment: This could be due to different version of admob sdk being used by you from the one given in the documentation. Try updating the admob sdk.

Comment: @NaimishSrivastava im indeed using an older play-services version which is play-services-ads:17.2.1' , but when i try to change it to the latest 18.2.0 i get errors because i don't use android x artifacts...

Comment: This method could be a part of the latest releases so the only option would be to update to use androidx artifacts. It's really quite simple to do refractor to androidx.

Comment: @NaimishSrivastava I know, but my problem is i'm using a 3rd party library called Glide for image loading from github and they didn't migrate to android x yet so when i change to android x this library gets alot of errors. Any workaround for this?

Comment: @NaimishSrivastava Is there a way i can still use latest version of play-services-ads without fully migrating to Android X?

Comment: The new versions of play and firebase libraries are being shipped with Androidx only so i think it won't be possible to side load them. For glide you can try - implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0', implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.9.0' , annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'

Comment: @NaimishSrivastava Now it's working because i migrated to Android x and Glide is also working so thanks for the help.